# Problems with preposition "TO"

Tags: prepositions

My teachers gave me some feedback and told me that I had a problem with the preposition "to." For example:

> I called to China Wok
>   I told to maria.

Those are mistakes that I made. So I need help with them, please.

Answer (score 1):

I can try to help with the second one. Your sentence

> I told to Maria

uses the verb "tell". "Tell" has two forms:

1. With two direct objects: tell `someone` `something`.
2. With one direct object and one indirect object (using the preposition "to"): tell `something` to `someone`.

So you can tell Maria a story, or tell a story to Maria.

In your sentence, "Maria" is an indirect object, but there is no direct object, so it is not in one of the two forms above, and is incorrect.